# iOS Google Map SDK : Change Google Map Zoom Level with GMSCameraUpdate:fitBounds:withEdgeInsets

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to change iOS Google Map SDK zoom level using with `GMSCameraUpdate:fitBounds:withEdgeInsets`. But the problem is the Google map is taking the default zoom level when i use `GMSCameraUpdate:fitBounds:withEdgeInsets`. Here am using `withEdgeInsets` to change map position. Any help will be appreciated. 
Below is my complete code.

```
GMSCoordinateBounds *markerBounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithPath:gmsPath];
GMSCameraUpdate *updatedCamera = [GMSCameraUpdate fitBounds:markerBounds withEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-500, 0, 0, 0)];
[mapView_ animateWithCameraUpdate:updatedCamera];
```

Here `gmsPath` contains multiple coordinates for `[GMSMutablePath path]`.

When i use `[mapView_ animateToZoom:10];` then `withEdgeInsets` is not working.

I searched google and stackoverflow but i could not find correct result.

Comment: Why do you use an inset of -500?

Comment: To move google map to TOP, not to the Center of the screen. I don't want to show all the markers Center of screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with `UIEdgeInsetsMake`. The following is the solution.

```
GMSCoordinateBounds *markerBounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithPath:gmsPath];
GMSCameraUpdate *updatedCamera = [GMSCameraUpdate fitBounds:markerBounds withEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(44, 0, self.view.frame.size.height - 180, 0)];
[mapView_ animateWithCameraUpdate:updatedCamera];
```

-180 is the available space above `UITableView`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably resize the map to fit in the available space, rather than use an edge inset to have the same effect. In particular, resizing the map would make sure that the Google logo is visible, which is a requirement of using the SDK.

If you don't want to do that, then I think you should use something like `UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 500, 0)`, ie a positive inset on the bottom edge, not a negative inset on the top edge. Instead of hard-coding `500`, you should use the height of your table (in points).

Comment: In my case `UIEdgeInsetsMake` will solve the problem. but only issue is changing the zooming level. Is there any alternative solution without resize the map itself or without using `UIEdgeInsetsMake`?